# Set element state in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I am cross-browser testing and debugging my website, specifically testing for Internet Explorer version 10. I am using IE's F12 developer tool, and I want to set an element state, such as hover or active, so I can modify the css associated with the element. I found this easy to do with Google Chrome and Firefox-Firebug. Does anyone know how to do this with IE?

Answer (score 0):

You can *view* the CSS applied in the various states, however you can't *set* a set.

---

To view the CSS applied in a state:

1. find the element you need
2. Open the developer tools
3. focus the developer tools' window
4. hover the element you want
5. Press F5 without moving the mouse
6. Ctrl+B and click on the element

**source:** SO Answer - [Is there a way to test CSS :hover in IE Developer tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573302/is-there-a-way-to-test-css-hover-in-ie-developer-tools/18868482#18868482)